# How to avoid Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric error on Azure app gateway

Tags: azure, azure-waf

We have an asp.net mvc application hosted in azure app service. The WAF policy on application gateway is blocking a post request with the "403 Forbidden" error. On firewall log, we see below error captured.

```js
{
  "timeStamp": "2023-07-25T04:19:52+00:00",
  "resourceId": "XXXX",
  "operationName": "ApplicationGatewayFirewall",
  "category": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog",
  "properties": {
    "instanceId": "appgw_0",
    "clientIp": "XXXX",
    "requestUri": "/Account/ForgotPassword",
    "ruleSetType": "OWASP CRS",
    "ruleSetVersion": "3.2",
    "ruleId": "920160",
    "ruleGroup": "REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT",
    "message": "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric.",
    "action": "Matched",
    "details": {
      "message": "Pattern match ^\\d+$ at REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length.",
      "data": "2",
      "file": "REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf",
      "line": "130"
    },
    "hostname": "dev.abc.com",
    "transactionId": "3d76839b7988f5963773b6016e3098d5",
    "policyId": "133#_subscriptions_c0978b9d-b809-45f4-aa76-391ceb2cfdba_resourceGroups_XXX_1_providers_Microsoft.Network_ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies_WAF-azuswa1easasdfe318",
    "policyScope": "Global",
    "policyScopeName": "Global",
    "engine": "Azwaf"
  }
}
```

I inspected the post request in Network tab & I see a valid content-length header. So, I am unaware of why this traffic is blocked on gateway & what is workaround for this other than disabling the particular rule.